References for coherent categories and coherent sites
I'm trying to understand the details of Grothendieck-Galois theorem in Caramello's Topological Galois Theory article.

Could you recommend me any reference for coherent categories and coherent sites?
Thank you in advance for any help.

As you are reading a paper writting by Caramello, it might be easiest to refer to her book as it will use the same notation and terminology (and I think it is well written): Theories, Sites, Toposes: Relating and studying mathematical theories through topos-theoretic 'bridges' by Olivia Caramello, Oxford University Press (2017). You can use the index in the back of the book to find where the relevant terms are defined and explained.
That being said, of course the Elephant should be mentioned as well: Sketches of an Elephant: A Topos Theory Compendium by Peter Johnstone, Oxford University Press (2002). In this case Section D3.3 in volume 2 would contain the most relevant information.
